# Excel, Vba, Asterisk, Syntax, text file

Tags: regex, excel, vba, replace

I'm using excel to open a text file, find a certain string and replace it with nothing/delete it. I'm having a hard time figuring out the proper syntax for an asterisk/wildcard apparently, and hopefully this will be an easy answer for someone!

Here's a brief example of my code, in case it has some hidden influence.

```
Sub ReplaceText()
Dim DataFind As String

Open "ORIGINAL\073347.TXT" For Binary As #1
DataFind = Space$(LOF(1))
Get #1, , DataFind
Close #1

                     '<< 073347 >>
DataFind = Replace(DataFind, "<< * >>", "")

Open "NEW\073347.TXT" For Output Access Write As #1
Print #1, DataFind
Close #1

End Sub
```

Basically I want to find a specific kind of string (syntax wise) in the text file, in this case it would be "<< 073347 >>" but I can't seem to find the correct syntax to use to find anything with << >> on either side, or potentially other things once I know what I'm doing wrong. "<< 073347 >>" works fine. I've tried "&" symbols, adding spaces, etc. maybe just not in the right context. Hopefully this is enough information. And thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Mid function and a loop to handle this:

```
    Sub ReplaceText()
    Dim DataFind As String
    Open "1.TXT" For Binary As #1
    DataFind = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , DataFind
    Close #1

                         '<< 073347 >>
    While InStr(DataFind, "<<") > 0 And InStr(DataFind, "<<") < InStr(DataFind, ">>")
        DataFind = Mid(DataFind, 1, InStr(DataFind, "<<") - 1) & Mid(DataFind, InStr(DataFind, ">>") + 2, Len(DataFind))
    Wend
    Open "1.TXT" For Output Access Write As #1
    Print #1, DataFind
    Close #1
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. All the answers were quite helpful. Using the mid function is definitely the least disappointing, but I might end up falling back on some RegEx stuff. Thanks to all three of you.

Comment: A little surprised at that response - the RegExp can run a single shot replacement rather than a potential long winded Mid loop.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do wildcard replaces using the Excel replace function.  You'll most likely have better luck using [Using Regex / vbscript](https://superuser.com/questions/181005/can-you-do-regular-expressions-in-excel-without-vbscript)

Answer (score 0):

The Replace function only search for an exact match. In order to replace a string according to a pattern, you should use regular expressions.

A good start is the tutorial http://www.macrostash.com/2011/10/08/simple-regular-expression-tutorial-for-excel-vba/ . After having a match, use the Mid() to replace the content.

Don't forget to first add "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions" reference via Tools --> References .

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using a [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp)

```
Sub ManipulateStrings()
    Dim strIn As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    'first and last sub-portions are matches, middle missing leading/trailing spaces   
    strIn = "<< 073347 >> ff <<fred>>, << fred >>"
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "<< .+? >>"
        If .test(strIn) Then
            MsgBox .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
        Else
            MsgBox "No matches"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```